# How to stop auto play of video in news feeds on facebook.com ?

Tags: facebook, settings, social-networking

I think automatically playing videos are new feature of Facebook.com. But the problem with this is they consume data unnecessarily(as i use data card for internet so want to save my data for purposeful things). So is there any way to stop videos from autoplaying ??

Comment: This site is for programming related questions, not Facebook related questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Go check Facebook’s Help section, or ask this in their help community.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check [this link](https://www.facebook.com/help/1406493312950827) for your answer or follow these steps:

1. From the top-right of Facebook, click and select "Settings"
2. Click "Videos" in the left menu
3. Click the dropdown menu next to "Auto-play Videos" and select "Off"